# Server log file into panel in extjs 3.X

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I need to display the server log file into the screen using ajax call. The panel need to render every 10 seconds to get updated log file. I tried with following code.

```
 var LogPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
     title : 'API LOG',
     width : '100%',
     height:265,
     autoScroll: true,
     listeners: {
            'render': function()
                {
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'logs/mylog.log',
                        success: function(response){
                            Ext.getCmp('logPanelId').update( response.responseText );
                        }
                    });                
                }
        }
});
 Ext.reg('logPanel', LogPanel);
```

- I cannot get properly aligned log data in the panel as available in the log file
- My log contains xml codes. but xml codes not displayed in the panel.
- one of my xml tag name is "input". but In the panel Html textfield was
  created.

guide me to solve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s = Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(s);
Ext.getCmp('logPanelId').update('<pre>' + s + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working fine. but the contents in the panel are center aligned. I need that should be left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things : 
1) read response as responseXML. Something like  Ext.getCmp('logPanelId').update( response.responseXML );

2) This enables a formatted xml . If your log file is bound a xml schema (which normally it is) , you should take a look at [XmlReader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.XmlReader). This will help you avoid the encoding and decoding overhead at the client side.

Comment: But my log files contains both xml and text content

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide sample input of your log file.